# Convert Output or Object in Array to Table Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, custom-object, pscustomobject

I created a custom object

```
$customsa = New-Object -TypeName psobject
$customsa | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value (Get-AzStorageAccount).StorageAccountName 
$customsa | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Tier -Value (Get-AzStorageAccount).AccessTier
$customsa | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Replication -Value (Get-AzStorageAccount).sku.Name
$customsa | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name AccountKind -Value (Get-AzStorageAccount).kind
$customsa | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ResourceGroupName -Value (Get-AzStorageAccount).ResourceGroupName
```

The output is an array format

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwuuZ.png)

However I want the output to show in a table format like this

[Desired Table format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6Gsc.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried?:

```
$customsa | Format-Table
# or
$customsa | Out-GridView
```

From your example:

```
$customsa = New-Object -TypeName psobject
$customsa | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value (Get-AzStorageAccount).StorageAccountName 
$customsa | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Tier -Value (Get-AzStorageAccount).AccessTier
$customsa | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Replication -Value (Get-AzStorageAccount).sku.Name
$customsa | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name AccountKind -Value (Get-AzStorageAccount).kind
$customsa | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ResourceGroupName -Value (Get-AzStorageAccount).ResourceGroupName

$customsa | Format-Table
```

Comment: yes. doesn't give good output

Comment: Can you elaborate? There is also the `$customsa | Out-GridView` which will open the results in a new window with more room.

Answer (score 0):

`Get-AzStorageAccount` is returning all of your storage accounts each time you run it so you are assigning the value of *all* storage accounts to each property when you're using `Add-Member`.

You should be able to get the same result using `Select-Object` which will create your `psobject` for you

```
Get-AzStorageAccount |
    Select-Object StorageAccountName, AccessTier, Kind, ResourceGroupName, @{name = 'SKU'; expression = { $_.sku.name }} |
        Format-Table
```